# git: how to interpret first log output row

Tags: git

I'm trying to find out where is described the first line of `git log` output:

```
commit 3739bae879edbfd55f8e0c42a5b5c29fe2d6f772 (HEAD -> master)
commit 53a9a3759d67c92ffde67523aecd8d7eba10c39b (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
commit 53a9a3759d67c92ffde67523aecd8d7eba10c39b (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
commit bbd140f23a4a9c42ff80a7776b725a3064d6c43e (HEAD, upstream/master, upstream/HEAD)
```

In particular, I'd like to understand the part in parentheses.
While I believe I can guess the first 2 items, I don't know what 3^ and 4^ are and I can't understand where they're described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the ["description" or "decoration" format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emdem), listing refnames that can be used to reach the commit.